# twitter Application-user authentication VS Application-only authentication

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0

I have a twitter app, which will access the user tweets and post on behalf of them too,
i was reading this documentation: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth
which says their are two type's of oauth i.e.

Application-user authentication
Application-only authentication

which one should i be using for oauth in my scenario, please suggest me the correct one.
thanx in advance.